# Core Plot LineChart : Add padding to the right of the graph

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, the rightmost plot seems to goto the right-edge of the graph, & is hardly seen (as you can see above; only part of the plot-symbol is visible). Even if I increment the xAxisRange by 1 in order to give some space in the right (so that thee is some space 'after' the rightmost plot), this extra space gets added to the left (i.e. leftmost/beginning of the graph) & not to the rightmost edge.

I have added code for padding in the chart initialization method:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
graph.paddingLeft   = 85.0;
graph.paddingTop    = 20.0;
graph.paddingRight  = 20.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 80.0;
```

This seem to add padding 'outside' the rectangle that's seen around the graph, & not 'within' it.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the length of the plot range.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. Let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

decrease the y.titleOffset = xx.0f;